# ¿Cómo almacenar un registro en laravel en caso de que solo venga un dato?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, postman

Buen día, sucede que quiero actualizar registros en Laravel 9, recibiendo la data a través del $request pero si de todos los campos solo se envía uno me marca el resto como nulos, y me devuelve un error, en caso de que solo se quiera actualizar el número de teléfono por ejemplo, cómo se haría?

```
public function updateProperty(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $property = Property::where('codpro', $id)->first();

        $property->address = $request->address;
        $property->neighborhood= $request->neighborhood;
        $property->phone= $request->phone;
        

        $property->save()
}
```

Aquí estoy apuntando a las columnas del registro en la base de datos, Pero en caso que en el $request solo venga el phone, me marca el resto como nulos y no deja actualizar el registro.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. No podemos adivinar que es lo que estás haciendo para poder ayudarte. Comparte el código que tienes para poder encontrar el error en el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer validaciones de cada uno de los campos que estás recibiendo desde tu frontend en el backend con Laravel y actualizarlos sólo si vienen en el request. También te vas a apoyar del método `has` disponible en el `$request`.

Puedes leer más sobre el método de `has` en la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present).

```
public function updateProperty(Request $request, $id)
{
    
    $property = Property::where('codpro', $id)->first();
    
    // Validas que el registro que estás obteniendo sea válido y exista
    if ( $property )
    {
        // Si existe, empezamos a actualizar solo si en el request vienen estos campos
        
        // Validamos si viene en el request el campo address, si sí viene, asignamos la propiedad al valor que correspondiente, de otra manera se ignorará este if
        if ( $request->has('address') )
        {
            $property->address = $request->address;
        }

        // Validamos si viene en el neighborhood el campo address, si sí viene, asignamos la propiedad al valor que correspondiente, de otra manera se ignorará este if
        if ( $request->has('neighborhood') )
        {
            $property->neighborhood = $request->neighborhood;
        }

        // Validamos si viene en el phone el campo address, si sí viene, asignamos la propiedad al valor que correspondiente, de otra manera se ignorará este if
        if ( $request->has('phone') )
        {
            $property->phone = $request->phone;
        }

        // Finalmente actualizamos el registro solo con las previas validaciones
        // En caso de que algún campo anterior validado no venga en la solicitud
        // no debería de generarse ningún error
        $property->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, amigo lml